# Google Script function to update Google Form Dropdowns populated by cell values in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

The following script will create a form with 4 sections.  The first section of the form lists three options (dropdown) and depending on which one you choose, it will jump to the relevant section to request more information about that particular option (more dropdowns).

I am populating the first section with the names of three sheets (sql_db_info, oracle_db_info, imanis_db_info)
I am populating the three different dependant sub sections using the rows in the first two columns of each sheet.

All of this works.

The problem I have is what I need to do to update the different sections if I change any values in the columns of the existing sheets or if I add new sheets.

If I add more sheets  (mongo_db_info, casandra_db_info) and their associated dependent sub sections (using the values in the new sheets),  it appends to the existing form (adding more sections).

I tried to delete and recreate the sections each time but that screws up the collection of the responses in the relevant sheet.  New columns are created and it spreads out of control.

So....I need to be able to just update the relevant sections by adding new entries and removing deleted entries  or by overwriting the dropdown entries without recreating the sections.

So, the looping has to work in case I add new sheets (new database type with new dependent sections) but recreating the Form each time wont cut it.

So.  Additional sheets, will add to the additional first section (sql, oracle, imanis, mongo, cassandra etc).
And the cell values in the first two columns of those sheets will provide the dropdowns for the subsequent two sections for each option chosen in the first section (sql,oracl,imanis etc).

How can I update the relevant dropdowns when I add new sheets or add/delete values from the columns in the sheets?

In the below code,  the dbMaker function works on the first run.

What do I need to do to get it to just update dropdowns on subsequent runs?

```
var ssID = "url id is put here";
var formID = "url id is put here"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
var form = FormApp.openById((formID));


//function clearAll(form){
// var form = FormApp.openById((formID));
//  var items=form.getItems();
//  Logger.log(items);
//  //if(items < 1 ) {
//  var d=0;//deleted items counter
//  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
//    form.deleteItem(i-d++);
//    
//  }
  //} 
//  dbMaker();
//}

function dbMaker() {

  //var message = 'The current time is ' + new Date().toString();
  //Logger.log(message);

  var sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(function(sheet) {return sheet.getName().match(/db_info/gi);});

  var dbSelect = form.addListItem().setTitle('DB Type').setRequired(true);



  var dbChoices = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var dbName = sheets[i].getName();
    var dbSection = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(dbName).setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);


    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    var nativetech = getnativetech(sheets[i]);
    var nativetech_Select = form.addListItem().setTitle('Native Technology' + ' Choice').setHelpText('Select the correct DB type').setRequired(true);

    var nativetech_Choices = [];

    for(var j = 0; j < nativetech.length; j++) {
      nativetech_Choices.push(nativetech_Select.createChoice(nativetech[j]));
      Logger.log('nativetech choices', nativetech[j]);
    }

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    var integratedtech = getintegratedtech(sheets[i]);
    var integratedtech_Select = form.addListItem().setTitle('Intregrated with company' + ' Choice').setHelpText('Select the correct option').setRequired(true);

    var integratedtech_Choices = [];
    for(var k = 0; k < integratedtech.length; k++) {
      integratedtech_Choices.push(integratedtech_Select.createChoice(integratedtech[k]));
      Logger.log('integratedtech choices', integratedtech[k]);
    }

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    


    nativetech_Select.setChoices(nativetech_Choices).setRequired(true);
    integratedtech_Select.setChoices(integratedtech_Choices).setRequired(true)

    dbChoices.push(dbSelect.createChoice(dbName, dbSection));

  }
  dbSelect.setChoices(dbChoices).setRequired(true);
}




function getnativetech(sheet) {
  var result1 = ""
  var nativetech_Values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var result1 = nativetech_Values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  if (e[0]) ar.push(e[0])
  return ar;
  }, []);  
  var nativetech = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < result1.length; i++) {

    Logger.log('result1',result1[i]);
    nativetech.push(nativetech_Values[i][0]);
  }
  return nativetech;
}


function getintegratedtech(sheet) {
  var result2 = ""
  var integratedtech_Values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var result2 = integratedtech_Values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  if (e[1]) ar.push(e[1])
  return ar;
  }, []);  
  var integratedtech = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < result2.length; i++) {

    Logger.log('result2',result2[i]);
    integratedtech.push(integratedtech_Values[i][1]);
  }
  return integratedtech;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the info before updating the fields, you can set conditionals that if a field is already there or you don't want it on the form it doesn't update it. Please consider also re-doing the question with a better approach, since this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes.  I knew the question might be difficult to interpret and wasnt surprised not to get responses.  You are also correct that a conditional approach is best for updating the form after the initial creation.  Thats what I am working on now.  Thanks for the suggestion.